# How do I reassign the first index of this matrix 'a' without changing 'b'?

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to change a[0][0] without changing the matrix b. Is there an easy way to do this? I tried to use b = list(a) and b = a[:] but no luck.

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]

b = a


print(a)
print(b)

a[0][0] = "WWWW"

print(a)
print(b)
```

## Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
[['WWWW', 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
[['WWWW', 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

This worked but it seems like there could be a better way?

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]

b = [[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        b[i][j] = a[i][j]


print(a)
print(b)

a[0][0] = "WWWW"

print(a)
print(b)
```

## Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
[['WWWW', 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lists are mutable.

[This link explains in detail what mutable objects are](https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/)

This doesn't work in your code because, you are using nested lists. If you were to do just a[0]="something", this wouldn't reflect in b however if you do something like this a[0][0]="wow" this would.

```
 b = a[:]
```

The nested list in both a and b still point towards the same block of memory.

To solve this try:

```
import copy
a = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

> [Explained in detail here](http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php)